# extract substring from string using javascript or jquery or regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
 var str = "<a alt="Complaint ID" class="filterTag" 
            href="javascript:void(0)">0005000003</a>"
    var result = "Complaint ID"
```

I wanted to extract alt value of anchor tag in the above string

Comment: Well you can use jQuery. `$(str).attr('alt')`

Comment: To the extent that using DOM selectors to address HTML which isn't regular, this has already been answered here: [jQuery get attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416179/jquery-get-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery:

```
$('<a alt="Complaint ID" class="filterTag" href="javascript:void(0)">0005000003</a>').attr("alt")
```

Or you can do it with plane JS:

```
var xmlString = '<a alt="Complaint ID" class="filterTag" href="javascript:void(0)">0005000003</a>'
, parser = new DOMParser()
, doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "text/xml");

console.log(doc.firstChild.getAttribute("alt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to make a string of HTML content as a element selector and then get the value of `alt` using `attr()`

```js
var str = '<a alt="Complaint ID" class="filterTag"  href="javascript:void(0)">0005000003 </a>';
var alt = $(str).attr('alt');
console.log(alt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```